# How to get first word from sentence in Swift

Tags: string, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to get first word from `String` sentence as variable. How to do that? I have Local notification and I need to use it's message first word as variable, is it possible? For `LocalNotifications` I use `LocalNotificationHelper` library for easier handling. Maybe there is logic problem but I do not think so. More like I do not know enough options in `Swift` language.

**Edit:** I also have the `nameField.text!` in `NSUserDefaults` as an array. I need to delete the message first word from that array. Right now I remove only the first object from that array but that is not solution for me because I need to delete the nameField.text! from that array when LocalNotification pops out and user click on button.

Here I create notification message:

```
LocalNotificationHelper.sharedInstance().scheduleNotificationWithKey("text", title: "see options(left)", message: nameField.text!+"some text", date: deadlinePicker.date, userInfo: userInfo)
```

Now I need the `message:nameField.text!` to be variable at app launch.

This is how I trigger notification button actions:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "someFunction:", name: IDENTIFIER, object: nil)
```

Comment: think about what defines a word and how you as a human extracts the first word, then do the same in code.

Comment: Why would you not use the user info ?? Or you mean this is to create the notification message text?

Comment: @Wain, check I edited my post. I want to receive it as variable not to create variable for that notification.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
let sentence = "First word needed"
let word = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ").first
print(word) // First
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split your sentence using the white space char and then extracting the first element.

```
let sentence = "What a wonderful world"
if let firstWord = sentence.characters.split(" ").first.map(String.init) {
    print(firstWord) // "What"
}
```

Comment: do I have to store this firstWord into NSUserDefaults then? Because on load I have to use it.

Comment: I did answer your question. If you have new questions please create a new post.

Comment: I still think you did not since my first word is always textField value. So it takes last entered one as last value and you just gave me code where it is constant.

Comment: @MaeseppTarvo: Please provide me an example input and related output so I can better understand.